# jQuery how to set selected values on top in multiple select box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, always-on-top

I'm working on a multiple select box which should not take up much space by default. Therefore it will expand when onmouseover.

When user has selected values, I want the selectbox to become the size of the number of selected values. This works, but the problem is that the selected values will not be in the top of the select box, the first one will always show on top, and this will make selected values hidden if its not in the top. How can I make sure that the first of the selected value always is on top when user leaves the select box?

I have posted the full example here. http://jsfiddle.net/pNu2b/3/

and this is the code I'm using:

```
<select id="yearOfBirth" name="yearOfBirth" size="4" multiple="multiple" style="cursor:pointer;" id="yearOfBirth">option value="" style="background-color:#000000; color:#FFFFFF;" selected="selected">Year of birth</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
</select>


$(document).ready(function() {

$("#yearOfBirth").on('mouseenter',function(){
$(this).animate({"size": "10"}, "fast");
});
$("#yearOfBirth").on('mouseleave',function(){
var countSize = $("#yearOfBirth :selected").length;
$(this).animate({"size": countSize+1}, "fast");
});

});
```

Just to clarify.
If 1997 and 1998 are selected. 1990 and 1991 will show when leaving the selectbox. I want to show the selected values. Like the right part in the image is correct, the left is wrong.
http://tinypic.com/r/1ie7mc/6

Comment: do you mean the selected values will change its indexes?

Comment: I mean if I select 1997 and 1998, they will not show when I leave the selectbox. Instead the unselected values 1990 and 1991 will show.

Comment: ok so if you want to hide it? then do you mean we will remove the selected values in the select box?

Comment: or this? http://jsfiddle.net/pNu2b/24/

Comment: THanks for your replies @Mahan. Maybe you are on to something, but I posted this image to explain better.
http://tinypic.com/r/1ie7mc/6

Comment: so its not like your sorting the contents but it automatically moves the selection scroll to the selected values?

Comment: @Mahan after some hours I got it working :) however there seems to be some problem with this in firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/3YXLq/

Answer (score 0):

Please try code...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#yearOfBirth").on('mouseenter',function(){ 
      $(this).attr('size',10);
  });
  $("#yearOfBirth").on('mouseleave',function(){
     var countSize = $("#yearOfBirth :selected").length;
     $(this).attr('size' ,countSize+1 );
  });
 });
```

​

Comment: This will not help. If I select 1997 and 1998, they will not show when I leave the selectbox. Instead the unselected values 1990 and 1991 will show.